# Do I need to nullcheck when I am using two nullable properties in my orderby?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with two properties, Lastname and Firstname. They are nullable and should be.

This is my codeline:

```
return memberlist.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.Firstname);
```

My question is if Lastname is null will it run the ThenBy() and Else I need to create a nullcheck? I want to make sure that it orderby Lastname and if its null then do it by Firstname.

Let's say I have a list that looks like this:

```
var data = new List<Member>
{
    new Member { FirstName = "null", LastName = "A" },
    new Member { FirstName = "B", LastName = null },
    new Member { FirstName = "A", LastName = null },
    new Member { FirstName = null , LastName = "B" },
    new Member { FirstName = "A" , LastName = "B" },
    new Member { FirstName = "B" , LastName = "A" },
};
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
A
A
A
B
B
B

var result = data.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName);
```

Comment: Have you tried? It shouldn't be too difficult to insert null into your member list …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will run the `ThenBy()`.

Essentially, all items with a `null` `LastName` property will be *then* ordered by `FirstName`.

`OrderBy()` will place `null` values before not null values.

In the following example, `result` returns the items in the order that they are declared:

```
var data = new List<Member>
{
    new Member { FirstName = "A", LastName = null },
    new Member { FirstName = "B", LastName = null },
    new Member { FirstName = "A", LastName = "NotNull" },
    new Member { FirstName = "B", LastName = "NotNull" }
};

var result = data.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName);
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments below and update of question, you can use something like the following to perform `OrderBy()` on a logical combination of `FirstName` and `LastName`:

```
var result = data.OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.LastName) ? x.FirstName : x.LastName)
                 .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
```

Comment: but what if I want A,A,B,B and not A,B,A,B ?

Comment: In that case, `data.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.LastName);`

Comment: Can expand on your question to give an example input with desired output?  I can then edit appropriately.